# How do I display a YouTube video in webViewer?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to play a video in my C# WinForm.

Here is what I have so far:

I have a webViewer control in my form, and the following code:

```
// Play YouTube video in webBrowser1
string url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5aCbWqKl-wU";
string html = "<html><head>";
html += "<meta content='IE=Edge' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>";
html += "<iframe id='video' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/{0}' style=\"padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; display: block;\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
html += "</body></html>";
webBrowser1.DocumentText = string.Format(html, url.Split('=')[1]);
```

Here is what it looks like when I run my app:

[image]

**The problem is that the video does not fill up the entire webViewer** (which is the white part in the image).

I have the webViewer1.Anchor property set to all, so when I resize the form, the webViewer resizes based on the form.

**Note:**

When the user clicks the fullscreen button the problem is fixed. But this is a bad solution for me because it's a bad experience for the user. Plus, the user may not know that they need to click the fullscreen button. This is what that looks like:

[image]

**How do I make the video take up the entire webViewer without the user having to click the fullscreen button?**

Also, as a side-question, when the user clicks the "YouTube" button, it opens Internet Explorer, and not the default browser. How do I fix this?

Comment: Instead of specifying height in percentage, can you specify it in px? try with 500px instead of 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix the styling of your page:

```cs
// Play YouTube video in webBrowser1
string url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5aCbWqKl-wU";
string html = "<html style='width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;'><head>";
html += "<meta content='IE=Edge' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>";
html += "</head><body style='width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;'>";
html += "<iframe id='video' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/{0}' style=\"padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; display: block;\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
html += "</body></html>";
webBrowser1.DocumentText = string.Format(html, url.Split('=')[1]);
```

This ensures that the HTML and BODY tags occupy 100% of the page, and that allows the child iframe to occupy 100% of the page. That generates this HTML:

```html
<html style='width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
    <head>
        <meta content='IE=Edge' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
    </head>
    <body style='width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;'>
        <iframe id='video' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/5aCbWqKl-wU' style="padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; display: block;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get the error: An error has occured in the script on this page. Line: 34. Char: 14. Error: Expected identifier. Code: 0. URL: https://www.youtube.com/s/player/7577aaa2/www-embed-player.vflset/www-embed-player.js.

Comment: @John Hmm. I just tested it and can confirm. I've added an alternative solution that definitely does work.

Comment: Thanks! Since you edited your answer, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set up an Aspect Ratio.
Checkout the document here

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_iframes.asp

Answer (score 0):

I am using vs2019. I don’t know why. After trying it, it is in a black state and does not display the video.

Comment: Please use the comments to start a thread discussion

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33861546)